# Need assistance with Android fixed footer for a linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have <.ImageView>`enter code here`s(icons) in my android layout xml file, which are encompassed by a `<ScrollView>`.

Eg.

```
<.ScrollView><br>
<.LinearLayout><br>
<.ImageView> ...<./ImageView><br>
<./LinearLayout><br>
<./ScrollView>
```

To this layout, i want to attach a fixed footer. Basically a small tab present on the bottom on the screen which stays even when I scroll to the all the way down or all the way to the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to write up layouts like this with a `LinearLayout` as root element and weights on the children to dynamically allocate screen estate. It keeps the layout definition compact and doesn't require defining extra ids.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView ... />
            <ImageView ... />
            ...
            <ImageView ... />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- footer here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using a `RelativeLayout` as root element, with the `ScrollView` positioned 'above' the bottom-aligned footer, however, is probably slightly better in terms of performance, although I doubt it'll make a noticable different in the case of a simple view hierarchy like this. The RelativeLayout approach does require assigning some ids (to at least the footer, I'd say).

Comment: Also I wanted to know what did you mean exactly by better performance if we used a relative layout.

Comment: Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. Especially when you start nesting `LinearLayout`s with non-zero weights, this is a bad thing, since the number of measurements increases exponentially. That's exactly why the Lint tool nowadays shows you a warning in these cases. Often (and also in this case) you can realise the same layout using a `RelativeLayout`. If you need an example, I'll be happy to add it to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

something like this..

```
<.ScrollView>
<.LinearLayout>
<.ImageView> ...<./ImageView>
<./LinearLayout>
<./ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<-- your footer here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try like this also..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbg"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```